# ios app crashes after language change

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, localization, crash, uistoryboard

I've a storyboard that contains a ViewController with the StoryboardID "PendingToursVC". In my code I do the following:

```
@try {
        self.pendingToursVC = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PendingToursVC"]; <-- app crashes on this line
    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {
        NSLog(@"exception:\n%@", [exception description]);
    }
```

The program is halted on this line and in the crash stack you can see that an objc_exception_throw (what ever that is) is thrown.

[image]

So, why is the exception not displayed in the console. This way I do not understand what is happening here. Any hints how to find out are appreciated.

Comment: One thing I can think of is, log is buffered and not flushed yet. Although very unlikely, that would be one reason why. I suggest putting logs right before the command, right after the command, and instead of printing the exception once, copy and paste that logging line like 100 times and see if that (somehow) makes a difference

Comment: You need to continue past the exception to have it log it to the console. My guess would be that nib doesn't exist, or is named something else.

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I found out and updated my question.

Comment: @toom: keep in mind that you can post an answer to your own question, so that future readers can quickly tell what you did to diagnose and resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for reading. The solution was, that I have two storyboards (german and english). In the english storyboard the viewcontroller exists. But I turned my iphone yesterday from spanish to german. So the app tries to retrieve the viewcontroller form the german storyboard. Hence it does not exist and crashes. That was a hell of an error.